# footnoterule not moving with footnote

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, footmisc

I'm using the `book` documentclass and the `footmisc` package.

I made some changes to the original footnote macros, and this causes the following problem when the footnoted word is on the last couple of lines of the page:

[image]

A minimal (not)working example:
[book.main.tex](http://pastebin.com/Uvi8UBpB)
[mylayout.sty](http://pastebin.com/5XdN0qjA)

If line 67. in mylayout.sty is commented out, the footnoterule and the footnote moves to the next page, which is the expected behaviour. It beats me why it leaves the rule on the prev. page otherwise.

Comment: Please add [full, but minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also, just compile the document without your modifications and see if it changes anything.

Comment: True, I should have provided one. Question edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for providing a MWE. However post here should be self-contained and therefore it should be part of the post and not use some external pastebin site. You can replace fill-texts with `\lipsum` or `\blindtext` from the packages of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from this:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\footwidth}\raggedright #1\end{minipage}
```

Comment out the `minipage` environment, leaving only `\raggedright #1` and you'll see the standard behaviour:

in the page where the `\footnote` command is invoked, the footnoterule is drawn, and, if the whole footnote text doesn't fit in the page, the text is properly split: some lines will be written in the first page, and the remaining text will continue in the next page; however, since you are enclosing the text in a `minipage`, and `minipage`s don't admit page breaks, the full footnote text is moved to the next page leaving a footnoterule without text in the first page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The designer gods above me somehow don't like that, that's why I tried putting it in a minipage. Is it possible to keep the footnote text together some other way, or they can't have their cake and eat it too?

Comment: @Nyiti: Change `\interfootnotelinepenalty`, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=splitfoot